# how to make tkinter canvas update?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have coded a bar chart in tkinter canvas and it is getting data from a list. However, when i update the list, the bar chart does not update. How can i fix this?

My code looks something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

data = [20, 15, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bar Graph")

c_width = 600 # Define it's width
c_height = 400  # Define it's height
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=c_width, height=c_height, bg='white')
c.pack()

# The variables below size the bar graph
y_stretch = 15  # The highest y = max_data_value * y_stretch
y_gap = 20  # The gap between lower canvas edge and x axis
x_stretch = 10  # Stretch x wide enough to fit the variables
x_width = 20  # The width of the x-axis
x_gap = 20  # The gap between left canvas edge and y axis

# A quick for loop to calculate the rectangle
for x, y in enumerate(data):

    # coordinates of each bar

    # Bottom left coordinate
    x0 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_gap

    # Top left coordinates
    y0 = c_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)

    # Bottom right coordinates
    x1 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_width + x_gap

    # Top right coordinates
    y1 = c_height - y_gap

    # Draw the bar
    c.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red")

    # Put the y value above the bar
    c.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor=tk.SW, text=str(y))

root.mainloop()

def update():
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
         barChartData.append(random.randint(1, 11))
         count = count + 1
    update()
update()
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: I don't see any barchart in your code. You collect data but you don't draw a barchart. The answer depends on exactly how you're drawing a barchart.

Comment: Ok i will edit to show my exact code

Comment: @BryanOakley what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to delete the old graph and create a new graph whenever you change the numbers.

You should do that by moving the code to draw the bar chart into a function.

```
def draw_barchart(data):
    c.delete("all")
    for x, y in enumerate(data):
        x0 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_gap
        y0 = c_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)
        x1 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_width + x_gap
        y1 = c_height - y_gap
        c.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red")
        c.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor=tk.SW, text=str(y))
```

You can then call this whenever the data changes, passing in the new data.

There are other problems with your code, however. You need to call `mainloop()` at the very end of your program since it won't return until the window is destroyed.

You also either need to use `after` to periodically update the data, or call tkinter's `update` function to allow the window to redraw itself.

Here's how to write the bottom part of the code to add data and redraw the graph every five seconds:

```
def update():
    count = 0
    for i in range(5):
        data.append(random.randint(1, 11))
    c.delete("all")
    draw_barchart(data)
    root.after(5000, update)

update()

root.mainloop()
```